# Django create one database entry and update those fields

Tags: django

For some reason there needs to be a database table with fields being updated. These fields are `attempt`, `success` and `failure`. I thought it'd be better to do using the Django ORM, but this needs to be the way ..

Problem hower is, that I get an array of array with data in it, that I will need to parse. How would I go about when there is not yet an entry in the database for this field?

### models.py

```
class SomeData(models.Model):
    attempt = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    success = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    failure = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

### views.py

```
    class PutSomeData(CreateOrUpdateAPIView):
        model = OtherModel

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.request.data

        for k in data:
            entry = OtherModel(
                field1=k[0],
                field2=k[1],
                field3=k[2]
            )
            entry.save()
            count = SomeData.objects.all()
            if not count:
                attempt, success, failure = 0, 0, 0
                data = SomeData(
                    attempt=attempt,
                    success=success,
                    failure=failure
                )
                data.save()
            else:
                data = SomeData.objects.last()
                if 'attempt' in k[2]:
                    data.attempt + 1
                elif 'success' in k[2]:
                    data.success + 1
                else:
                    data.failure + 1
                data.save()
```

I was thinking something like this for now, but this is ofcourse a stupid thing to do, and besides that it will always skip the first one in the array and is thus inaccurate. This is just something I have for now, but I do not know how to make this better and more elegant. Any thoughts?

Edit: to be a bit more clear: problem is that there are no initial fields for now, otherwise i could just increment the fields like i also do, but now I have to look if there is an entry already (it will otherwise complain about NoneType not having 'attempt' ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a migration with initial data, so that you'll be sure the entry exists.

Also, for a table with global values that is going to have only one row I would suggest using table with rows `key` and `value` (or similar), so that when you'll need to add new global values you won't need to do a schema migration.